# Opncv cascadetraining.exe's negative data

Tags: opencv, cascade-classifier

Could You please explain me, how opencv `cascadetraining.exe` uses negative images?

If I have in negative.txt file only let say specified 30 images  but I put negNum 3000, it will use only 30 out of them, or, It gets all possible permutations (random rectangles)?

Comment: see this my help you: http://note.sonots.com/SciSoftware/haartraining.html#d53fc8c9